# Trouble with Linq in group by query

Tags: linq, lambda

Maybe someone knows how to achieve this kind of query in linq (or lambda).

I have this set in a list

[image: example of data]

Filter: My input will be code 100 and 101, I need to get the "values", in this example = 1, 2.

Problem: If you input 100 and 101, you´ll get 3 results, because of 100 from group 1 and group 2. I just need the pair that matches in the same group. (And you don´t have group as an input param)

How can I solve this if the group fully exists?

thanks!

Comment: How is your input "100 and 101" exactly? What is the data structure here? It would help if you'd provide a short but complete example in code. Additionally, what would the values be if there was *also* a "code=101, value=5, group=2" row? What about if there was a "code 102, value=6, group=1" row? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Input is a enumerable with bouth values, the rest is not important for the question, cause you could have thousands of variables, I just need to achieve that result. If other data is there present in the future, i'll handle it. Thanks.!

Comment: Am I right in thinking that with the table you have here the only inputs you would ever have would either be `100` & `101` or else `100` & `103`? That is, you would never have an input that wasn't a full group? Further, could you have a group that perfectly matched another group? (e.g. could rows exist with `100:5:3` and `101:6:3` hence meaning group 3 also matched)?

Comment: Don't describe it, add code. And the rest absolutely *is* important for the question, in order to understand what rules you're trying to implement. If you want people to help you, you'll need to give more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with a simple representation in code of what you have in a picture:

```
var list = new[]
{
  new{code = 100, value = 1, group =  1},
  new{code = 101, value = 2, group =  1},
  new{code = 100, value = 3, group =  2},
  new{code = 103, value = 4, group =  2},
};
var inp = new[]{100, 103};
```

Then we can do:

```
list
  .GroupBy(el => el.group) // Group by the "group" field.
  .Where(grp => !inp.Except(grp.Select(el => el.code)).Any()) // Exclude groups that don't contain all input values
  .Single() // Obtain the only such group (with a check that there is only one)
  .Select(el => el.value); // Obtain the "value" fields.
```

If you could perhaps have inputs that were a subset of the "code" fields of some groups, you could also check that you match all of the group completely by excluding groups which have a different size:

```
list
  .GroupBy(el => el.group)
  .Where(grp =>
    grp.Count‎() == inp.Count()
    && !inp.Except(grp.Select(el => el.code)).Any())
  .Single()
  .Select(el => el.value);
```

There are other variations that match other possible interpretations of your question (e.g. I'm assuming there can be only one matching group, but that wasn't clear).

Comment: Cool!, the answer under "then we can do" worked sweet! thanks!, also worked with a non-linq method that didn´t know called "SequenceEqual", Maybe you could group values, and return only the group that SequenceEqual = true?

Comment: The Linq-method `SequenceEqual` will consider two sequences to be equal if they have matching items in the same order. `sequenceA.Count() == sequenceB.Count() && !sequenceA.Except(sequenceB).Any()` will match two sequences ignoring order. Use whichever is more appropriate. Given sequences known to be in the same order, this is of course the same, but `SequenceEqual` would be faster in that case.

Comment: didn't know about the order... now i need to check other things where I applied :P thanks.